# Сортировка карты

Tags: сортировка, java

Как отсортировать карту по возрастанию, по значениям. По ключам - получается, а вот по значениям никак.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
final Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("C", 7);
map.put("B", 3);
map.put("A", 5);

final Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
        return map.get(lhs).compareTo(map.get(rhs));
    }
});
sortedMap.putAll(map);

for (final Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s = %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
B = 3
A = 5
C = 7
```

Comment: Только вот, при повторяющихся значениях, идет переписвование

Comment: Можете поподробнее объяснить, в чём у вас возникла проблема?

Comment: Уже нашел как разрешить эту задачку

Comment: @JAVAvladuxa, могли бы и озвучить решение. Ладно, сделаю это за вас. В компараторе вместо 

    return map.get(lhs).compareTo(map.get(rhs));

прописываем

    int result = map.get(lhs).compareTo(map.get(rhs));
    return result == 0 ? -1 : result;

Comment: @fori1ton, тут проблема **повторяющихся** значений ключей (результат compare)

    

    public interface Map<K,V>
    
      An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain  duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value. 

из http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html